# Limit number of cols can be typed in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea and input [type=image] positioned (absolute) inside it at the end.

When user types a text, text might appear under this image like this [image: My example]

But what I want is to be as Google Translator's version - to limit number of cols  that can be typed or more free space for icon[image: Google Translator]

Here's my code

```css
#cross {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -19px;
  margin-top: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6" id="txtbox1">
  <input type="image" onclick="clearMessageArea('#userMessage')" src="img/cross.svg" id="cross" style="width: 14px; height: 14px" />
  <textarea class="form-control" id="userMessage" rows="6" style="resize: none"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: use padding-right :14px on text area.

Comment: _"I want is to be as Google Translator's version"_ You could always use inspect element on Google Translator, see how they've done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have some `padding-right` to avoid having characters going till the right edge. But that means that other lines will also not go till the right edge.

```css
#cross {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -19px;
  margin-top: 36px;
}

#userMessage {
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6" id="txtbox1">
  <input type="image" onclick="clearMessageArea('#userMessage')" src="https://placehold.it/14" id="cross" style="width: 14px; height: 14px" />
  <textarea class="form-control" id="userMessage" rows="6" style="resize: none"></textarea>
</div>
```

Update: Google also uses `padding-right: 20px` for this. You can check [here](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/).

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that padding will affect text, not textarea by itself

Answer (score 1):

apply padding-right to the text area. see working example below.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.wrap{
  position: relative;
}
.close{
  position:absolute;
  right:4px;
  top:0;
}
textarea{
  padding-right:14px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'wrap'>
<span class = 'close'>x</span>
<textarea  name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">
  
</textarea>  
</div>
```